# Play sound in iOS device in react-native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-sound

In my app I have a feature that plays a sound when a message is received it will notify the user by playing a sound file, the app works using **react-native-sound** fine in Android but in iOS I keep getting this error:

[image]

Code I am using for initializing the sound:

```
import Sound from "react-native-sound"

// Load the sound file 'whoosh.mp3' from the app bundle
// See notes below about preloading sounds within initialization code below.
var message_received = new Sound(require("../../res/audio/Page_Turn.mp3"), Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
      return;
    }
    // loaded successfully
    console.log('duration in seconds: ' + message_received.getDuration() + 'number of channels: ' + message_received.getNumberOfChannels());
});
```

The method that I call after initializing sound file:

```
message_received.play()
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: from react-native-sound doc: iOS: Open Xcode and add your sound files to the project (Right-click the project and select Add Files to [PROJECTNAME]).
Then you can call it like new Sound('Page_Turn.mp3',

Comment: I did that and still getting same error.

Comment: the error appears when you do .play() or when you init the sound?

Comment: I think the error appears when it loads the file I set a breakpoint before it.

Comment: @llario your solution worked thanks!

Comment: Great! Can you accept my answer please? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `react-native-sound` doc:

> iOS: Open Xcode and add your sound files to the project (Right-click
>   the project and select Add Files to [PROJECTNAME]).

Then you can call it

`new Sound('Page_Turn.mp3',`

Answer (score 3):

1. If you use `require(filepath)`, you don't need `Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE`, the second param is callback:

   new Sound(require("../../res/audio/Page_Turn.mp3"), (error) => {})
2. `play` function should be called after initialising successfully

   var message_received = new Sound(require("../../res/audio/Page_Turn.mp3"), (error) => {
   if (error) {
     console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
     return;
   }
   // loaded successfully
   message_received.play()
   });
3. Remember to add(references) your .mp3 files into xcode, re-run `react-native run-ios`.

This code example contains many use-cases: https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound-demo/blob/master/main.js